# Editor - How to highlight applied controls

Tags: primefaces

How can we highlight the controls in the tool bar which have already been applied, like in Microsoft Word.

For instance, if a word has been made bold & underlined, then when we click on that word, the controls for Bold & Underline are displayed highlighted.

Comment: Thus is not a PrimeFaces issue but of the underlying cleditor.  Check there.  But alzo try the PrimeFaces Extensions editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used primefaces extensions' editor.